# fetching multiple urls from an api

Tags: javascript

Basically I am working with a star wars API called swapi (i haven't worked with APIs before) and I am fetching the data with a simple async-await function.

My goal is to get all the movies that API holds (a total of 6 of them) I am using a template tag in HTML and I'm cloning it in javascript and then displaying all 6 movies.

So to clarify, I am getting an array of 6 objects that I'm displaying the title of each movie in HTML without a problem since the title is in a string format, but every object has also a  key (characters) that has a value of an array and inside that array is a big list of characters that play in the movie but they are in a URL format (http://swapi.dev/api/people/1/)  except the last number in the URL changes for each of them.

Is there a smart way to fetch and display all the character names for each movie they have played in? because all the ways I'm trying aren't working. The ideal solution would be to display all the characters that have played in each movie and having the possibility to click on them and seeing a few details that they hold.

[image: console log of movies object]

Comment: Guess you would need some sort of promise all with a bunch of http calls.

Comment: rest falls apart for edge cases, like when multiple (get, update and delete) as your seeing. Either implement `/people?ids=1,2,3,4` or `/people?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4` or `/people?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3&ids[]=3`, or make diff endpoint which groups all i.e `/film/1/people` or make multiple calls (eww)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone could you please elaborate on that? Sorry im still a noob :/

Comment: since we are not talking large amounts of data, you could make one query for all films (6) and one query for all people (82) and map them yourself (one two queries and two, small, result sets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is my guess (I have no time to test this second, but will shortly and get this answer working don't pass.)

```
async function getSWdata(){
await fetch('starwars api')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>data.people.map(async (x)=>await fetch(x).then(res=>res.json())));
}
```

the things I'm unsure about are the exact syntax of async => functions, or any complications of async functions nested inside an async function...
but this might get you on the right track regardless.

EDIT:::
this below is working mostly for me (I am iffy sure on promises => there are improvements to be made)

```
async function getSWdata(){
    return  await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/films')
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>
        {      
        const r = data.results.map((results)=>
            {
            const toons = results.characters.map(async (toon)=>await fetch(toon).then(res=>res.json()))
            results.characters = toons;
            return results;
            })
            data.results = r;
           return data; 
    });
    }
const SWData = getSWdata();
console.log(SWData);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i tried it and it doesn't look to be working for me, maybe i am doing something wrong, i'm not sure

Comment: what API address are you using exactly for the first call. I'm working in theory here, not in practice. is it just https://swapi.dev/api/films ? or are there parameters?

Comment: it is just the swapi.dev/api/films as you said and i'm getting back an array of 6 objects (the movies)

Comment: ah, so in the results part returns multiple movies, and for each movie you want to get the characters appended directly to that object that gets returned instead of the url string, correct?? if so: structure wise - the final result will be similar - it's just now making point to the right place.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i am trying to do here. Because now I am getting back  URL strings as you said and not the character names which is the goal. Thanks again for your reply

Comment: just the name, or more info, the reason it's in a url string is becuase it's probably a json object with a bunch of other data on it, but you want to replace the url strings with name strings?

Comment: the ideal solution would be to get the name that somehow would be clickable and some kind of a modal would pop up with the bunch of other data inside there

Comment: ah, so probably just attach the return object and deal with it all in the UI logic and not in the fetch logic. will look more into it later tonight. it's simple, just wiring.